# API Failure Sqlite

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I ran the Windows 8 App Certification Kit on my app and it says it will fail because of Sqllite. Am I referencing code incorrectly or can I ignore this problem? Here is the response:

> Impact if not fixed:  Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps violates the Windows Store certification requirements.
>
> - API `__CppXcptFilter` in `msvcr110.dll` is not supported for this
>     application type. `sqlite3.dll` calls this API.
> - API `__clean_type_info_names_internal` in `msvcr110.dll` is not supported
>     for this application type. `sqlite3.dll` calls this API.
> - API `__crtTerminateProcess` in `msvcr110.dll` is not supported for this
>     application type. `sqlite3.dll` calls this API.
> - API `__crtUnhandledException` in `msvcr110.dll` is not supported for this
>     application type. `sqlite3.dll` calls this API.

I am referencing this file:

```
SQLite for Windows Runtime
SQLite.WinRT, Version=3.7.14
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WinRT\3.7.14\
```

In my Windows 8 Metro app using XAML.

Here are my references:

Metro App:

[image]

Class Lib

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I built the software in release mode. I then deployed it to the simulator and it passed. When you run the Windows App Certification Kit, you must put the app in release mode and deploy to the simulator. Otherwise, the system uses the last build. In that case, it was my debug version.

Comment: I don't know how to deploy app to the simulator during Windows App Certification Test. Please help me. I'm also facing the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package.

This is another Extensions SDK, just like the SQLite for Windows Runtime Extensions SDK, and a reference can be added the same way that you added a reference to SQLite:   in the Reference Manager dialog, you can find it under Windows -> Extensions.

The SQLite for Windows Runtime SDK depends on the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package (all native SDKs and components require the Visual C++ Runtime Package).  If you highlight the SQLite for Windows Runtime SDK in the Reference Manager, you'll see on the right side of the dialog that the Visual C++ Runtime Package is listed as a dependency (it's listed as "Microsoft.VCLibs, version=11.0," which is rather unfortunate).

Comment: Please see the new images about references. I believe I have added these, James. Kindly confirm that I am correct.

Comment: Are you testing a Release build with WACK?  Or a Debug build?  Note that you must test a Release build.

Comment: I've followed instructions on this link: https://github.com/mbrit/sqlite-metrostyle but I've got the same store certification error

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the manifest XML file by adding the following

```
<Dependencies><PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.110.00" MinVersion="11.0.0.0" /></Dependencies>
```

Next time your app will pass certification

Comment: My manifest XML file have no any Dependencies field. Please help what I'm doing wrong?