# Windows Certification kit failure using sqlite in Class Library

Tags: windows, sqlite

In my Windows Store App I use a Class Library that uses the SQlite for Windows Runtime 3.7.15.2. 
I have used the Tim Heuers instructions 
[here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx).
My App is running without problems, the App Packages are created without a problem but in windows certification process I get the same errors all the time whatever I try.
The errors are:

```
 - API sqlite3_bind_blob in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_bind_double in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_bind_int in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_bind_int64 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_bind_null in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_bind_parameter_index in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_bind_text16 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_busy_timeout in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. 
.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_changes in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_close in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_column_blob in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_column_bytes in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_column_count in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_column_double in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_column_int in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. .dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_column_int64 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. .dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_column_name in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_column_name16 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_column_text in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_column_text16 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_column_type in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_config in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_errmsg16 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_finalize in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_last_insert_rowid in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_open in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_open16 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_open_v2 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_prepare_v2 in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_reset in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
 - API sqlite3_step in sqlite3.dll is not supported for this application type. LibraryName.dll calls this API.
```

I think I've tried everything. 
I saw this
[API Failure Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361723/api-failure-sqlite)
 problem that it looks the same but it didn't helped
I run out of ideas....